# python 4 way recursive Flood Fill of a curve

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, flood-fill

I am trying to use the flood fill algorithm to fill in one of the two colors of this curve, which is defined with red being 1 and blue being zero. However, when I try to run my code, it says that the syntax for the line `if m[i][j]=1:` is incorrect.  Any advice on how to debug this?  Thanks.  In this code `m` is the matrix I am working in and `i` and `j` are my xy variables

```
from pylab import *
m=zeroes((100,100))

for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        m[i,j]=sin(i+j+0.1*i*j+0.1*j*j)+cos(i-j+0.2*i*i)

n=m.copy()
n[n>0]=1
n[n<0]=0
imshow(n)

def floodfill (m,i,j):
    if m[i][j]=1: 
       m[i][j]=0

        if i>0:
            floodfill(matrix,i-1,j)
        if i < len(m[y]) - 1:
            floodfill(m, i+1, j)
        if j>0:   
            floodfill(m, i, j-1)

            floodfill(m, i, j-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post the exact error, but I can tell you that this is incorrect:

```
m[i,j]=sin(i+j+0.1*i*j+0.1*j*j)+cos(i-j+0.2*i*i)
```

`m[i,j]` is incorrect.  `i,j` is a tuple, but list indices (the thing inside the `m[]` brackets) can only be integers

Answer (score 2):

Values are to be compared for equality using `==` operator rather than a single `=` which is used for assignment expressions. So you should replace `if m[i][j]=1:` with `if m[i][j] == 1`.

And BTW, it did say "Syntax Error", so you should check the syntax of the line highlighted. That's your hint for debugging.